# Using System.Drawing to draw a crosshair on the desktop?

Tags: c#, drawing, screen, center

I'm trying to create a very small c# utility application that will utilize System.Drawing to draw a full screen, static, fixed cross-hair on my desktop so that I can align some desktop items to the relevant screen center.

I tried looking up a few examples but didn't come up with a whole lot and was wondering if anyone had any experience in this area.

I would prefer not making a transparent full screen window to accomplish this feat if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Loads of issues come up when you try this.  For one thing, you don't own the desktop, so you never have complete control of it as to when it gets invalidated.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr dc);

private void DrawDeskTop()
{
  IntPtr desk = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desk))
  {
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle((SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - 4, (SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height / 2) - 20, 8, 40));
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle((SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - 20, (SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height / 2) - 4, 40, 8));
  }
  ReleaseDC(desk);
}
```

When this runs, it will look great.  But as soon as you move your form over the center or move other windows, the plus sign will disappear, so you will have to draw it again, and again, and again.

Comment: Nice and simple! I like it. Like you said, it has a few holes but works as explained!

Answer (score 1):

You can't draw on the desktop at the native level (possibly excluding some hacked in support for Win16 that would disable composition and all sorts of other horribleness), so certainly not with `System.Drawing`. To do this, you would have to create a transparent window of at least the size of the image and draw on that.

Comment: Sort of elaborating on this idea of using the full screen transparent window, wouldn't this also make the Pen transparent on the form? how do you get around that?

Comment: Transparent doesn't mean invisible. I could give some native examples on how to implement them (I'd use `WS_EX_LAYERED` and implementing `WM_PAINT`), but I'm not familiar enough with Forms to know if it's even possible in it. PS: You actually want the window to be as small as possible for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reason for wanting to use code to accomplish this? I would use your favorite paint program and create an Image. Set that Image as your desktop background and that should give you the same result as what your asking to do in code (and much quicker).

If you have to do this with code I would look into using WPF. It will simplify the transparancy issue. However, you still have an app up over the top of your desktop. You will have to deal with that issue (and maybe a few others).

Comment: Billy, I don't think this is an overly complex issue I'm just not well versed in the graphics library. While your idea would in theory work, I'd much rather have a utility for this purpose.

Comment: Using the System.Drawing namespace implies that you are using WinForms to create this app. If you get into the GDI+ graphics, it can get ugly quick. I don't really know how to go about doing it without making the full screen window transparent. Your question also implies that you will have the app up over the top of the desktop... so you will have to allow interaction with the desktop thru your app. I can think of a few other issues also. I'm not an expert in this area, so I would like to see an easier approach also.

Comment: Billy, I was afraid this was going to be the case and sincerely appreciate your feedback / advise in this matter. I think I'm going to go with the cheat method of using a full screen transparent window and using the Pen to draw on the form.