# Line (Crosshair) in WPF not updating when coordinates are updated with mouse move event - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, line

I'm trying to create a cross-hair out of two lines on a WPF canvas.

I'm finding that when I initialize the lines they draw correctly.
But when I update the coordinates of the lines using the mouse move event, the lines are not updating.

Why are the lines not updating when the coordinates of the point `currentMousePoint  are updated?

```
public CADControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    //(500, 500) added just to test the lines appear which they do.
    private Point currentMousePoint = new Point(500,500);

    private void CadCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentMousePoint = e.GetPosition(this);
        //coordinates appear to update correctly in the console
        Console.WriteLine("x: " + currentMousePoint.X + "  y: " + currentMousePoint.Y);
        InvalidateVisual();
        UpdateLayout();
    }

    private double screenWidth;
    private double screenHeight;

    private void DrawCursorCrosshair()
    {
        screenWidth = CadCanvas.ActualWidth;
        screenHeight = CadCanvas.ActualHeight;

        Line horizontalLine = new Line();
        horizontalLine.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        horizontalLine.X1 = 0;
        horizontalLine.X2 = screenWidth;
        horizontalLine.Y1 = currentMousePoint.X;
        horizontalLine.Y2 = currentMousePoint.X;

        CadCanvas.Children.Add(horizontalLine);

        Line verticalLine = new Line();
        verticalLine.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        verticalLine.X1 = currentMousePoint.X;
        verticalLine.X2 = currentMousePoint.X;
        verticalLine.Y1 = 0;
        verticalLine.Y2 = screenHeight;

        CadCanvas.Children.Add(verticalLine);

    }

    private void CadCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawCursorCrosshair();
    }
```

Comment: The `Cursor` object already has a CrossHair option.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A crosshair that covers the whole window??

Comment: What makes you think the Lines would magically change their position just because the currentMousePoint field changes its value? Keep references to both Lines and update their properties in CadCanvas_MouseMove. Calling InvalidateVisual or UpdateLayout is totally useless.

Comment: @Clemens: Well, no, of course not.  Naturally, I could have sussed that out by reading the code, but wouldn't it be nice to know that in the actual question as well?

Comment: https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/m38179-Full-screen-cross-hair-cursor#post38179

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988774/using-system-drawing-to-draw-a-crosshair-on-the-desktop

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've set the lines to be equal to the canvas width and height. The property name ScreenWidth is missleading. I'm not interested in the cursor option as I want to learn how to update lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the reference to your lines and update them in the MouseMove event handler:

```
private Line _v;
private Line _h;
```

add in `DrawCursorCrosshair`:

```
_h = horizontalLine;
_v = verticalLine;
```

and in `CadCanvas_MouseMove` (after `currentMousePoint` is updated):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(_v, currentMousePoint.X);
Canvas.SetTop(_h, currentMousePoint.Y);
```

and set a static position to the lines in `DrawCursorCrosshair`:

```
verticalLine.X1 = 0;
verticalLine.X2 = 0;

horizontalLine.Y1 = 0;
horizontalLine.Y2 = 0;
```